# Can AWS be used as android back end? Or AWS is used by back end program?

Tags: java, android, web-services, google-app-engine, amazon-web-services

Is it correct that Android application which communicates with external database (somewhere on the server), requires web service (e.g. java web service)?

Is that web service an actual back end application which directly communicate with the DB?

Is this service, I am talking about, the same thing what AWS or google cloud offers, or am I messing it up?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijti.html

Comment: You do not need "the cloud" for webservices.  They've been around for a long long time.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot nor do I want your money.  Spend a little bit of time reading (google) about creating webservices.

Comment: I understand what you mean, I just needed to know few simple things which I can't find answers to. I know that AWS is providing some services but I am unable to understand why to use them, if I can build simple webservice which communicates with db and that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud providers can provide you computers and other hardware to run your back end server on and in some cases can provide you some or all of the services you need in your back end, obviously depending on what your app actually needs to do.

For example, AWS provides identify verification services, streaming recording backend services, notifications etc. You still need to do work to integrate your app with them but they do a lot of the heavy lifting for you.

Deciding whether to use the services or just the HW with your own services built on top is an architectural and business decision really.

You may want to balance ease of integration against vendor lock in (i.e. being tied to a single cloud provider to run your back end).

Personally, I like architectures that can be ported between cloud providers - you can still build on non cloud provider 3rd party service building block software if you want.

Having said that, AWS and Google have almost certainly put a lot of effort and thought into making their service building blocks easy to integrate and scalable so you may find their ecosystems work for you.